# Html.EditorFor and custom format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I got a property in my model which is a `DateTime` . I would like to get an empty `<input />` (instead of one containing ***'0001-01-01 00:00:00'***) if the property contains `DateTime.MinValue`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution I've found working for me was to add strongly typed partial view (for `System.DateTime`) and put it in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` directory. File `DateTime.cshtml` looks pretty much like this:

```
@model System.DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model == DateTime.MinValue ? "" : Model.ToShortDateString())
```

This will however format all your DateTime fields.

More information can be found in [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx) article.

Answer (score 2):

Write an [extension helper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) method:

```
public static class DateTimeHelper
{
    public static string MyEditor(this HtmlHelper helper, DateTime date)
    {
        if (date.Equals(DateTime.MinValue))
        {
            // return your an empty input: helper.TextBox ...
        }
        // return helper.EditorFor your datetime
    }
}
```

Then, from you view:

```
<%= Html.MyEditor(Model.YourDateTimeField) %>
```